# Deploy asp.net web page(aspx) into sharepoint 2013 without visual studio

Tags: 2013, asp.net

I have developed a asp.net web application which has some asp.net webforms(aspx pages) in it.I have tried to deploy those into sharepoint without visual studio.
I have manually copied all the project files as folder and pasted into sharepoint layouts folder inside 15 hive. Then I tried to access the webpage from sharepoint site like below. ex:URL of the `site/_layouts/foldername/test.aspx` .

I am getting parser error which says could not load type **the page**
Will this approach work in SharePoint? Is there any possibility to deploy asp.net pages without creating SharePoint project from visual studio?

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

You also can create page in site pages. Simply to go site content ->Site Page library -> you can create new page there only if you dont want to write any script there. Or open SharePoint designer, Go to site pages -> in page tab, you can create aspx page and also can change source code.

Comment: Your answer is not relevant to my question.please read the question once again.